# storing and accessing mp3 files using c#

Tags: c#, mp3

I'm doing a web application where people will be able to stream sounds of all sorts.

I'm aiming for a lot of sounds, and my question is this: what is the best, most efficient way of storing the MP3s for streaming?

Right now, I have them all stored in one folder with an Id as file name. I then have a corresponding row in the database that stores all the sound data, like category; type of sound and stuff like that. So when someone wants to stream a file, my application asks the database for the Id and then returns a URL for the stream.

Can this be done in a more efficient way? If so, how?

Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are going the right way. Lots of thing depends upon what your client is (i.e. browser or WinForm).

Some suggestions:

1. You can use web services to retrieve data from database. This will help if you want to decouple UI from database.
2. You can keep all your files on different servers, if the number of them is huge; and store their absolute URLs in a database.
3. Approach mentioned above will also help you in hosting media files and services/database on a different server.

If you have any specific questions, it will be easier to answer. Anyways hope this helps you.